# How to save more pointers in one array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, instance

I want to make a pointer to an instance of a class. Many instances - that is why I made an array which saves all of those.
But how can I set the value of a pointer in a class to 0?
That is the code... Maybe you know what I'm talking about

```
public:
    CCharacter *pTeamMember[15];
```

And in another file:

```
pTeams[team]->pTeamMember = 0;
```

It causes following error.

> error C2440: '=' can't convert 'int' into 'CCharacter *[15]

What I don't understand is, that this don't causes any errors:

```
public:
    Team *pTeams[31];
```

And in another file:

```
pTeams[i] = 0;
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: what is `CCharacter` and `Team`?

Comment: sorry, try: `pTeams[team]->pTeamMember[member] = 0;` (member being the corresponding index)

Comment: Your first erroneous assignment attempts to assign an integral constant to an *array*. Arrays are not allowed as lvalues in an assignment expression. Their "value" is fixed (the address of the first element in the array) and cannot be changed. Your second example is allowed because you're assigning to a *pointer* residing *in* an array of pointers. This is the fundamental difference between pointers and arrays; Pointers **hold** addresses; arrays **are** addresses.

Comment: Don't use an array, use `std::vector<CCharacter *>` or even better, a vector of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pTeamMember` isn't a pointer. It's an array of pointers-to-`CCharacter`.

In your second example, you're assigning to one of the pointers *in* the array. You could do the same with `pTeamMember`:

```
pTeams[team]->pTeamMember[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a pointer to 0 (presuming you mean point at nothing), you can do the following. Note that you can use 0 or nullptr (which is valid as of C++ 11)

`int *p = nullptr;`

In regards to your specific example, change

`pTeams[team]->pTeamMember=0;`

to

`pTeams[team]->pTeamMember[index]=0;`